# Express Middleware Setting Header Error

Tags: express, middleware

I'm trying to implementation a fairly simple middleware function to my Express application that just adds a `useCache` value to the request object being passed to the main handler but for some reason, I'm getting a `Can't set headers after they were sent` error.

```
const cacheControl = (req, res, next) => {
  if (lastPulled === null) lastPulled = Date().getDay()
  req.useCache = Date().getDay() === lastPulled
  next()
}

app.use(cacheControl)
app.get('/missions', (req, res) => {
  if (req.useCache) res.status(200).json({ result: cache })

  fetch(dumpUrl)
    .then(data => data.text())
    .then(result => {
      cache = result
      res.status(200).json({ result })
    })
    .catch(e => res.status(500).json({ result: e.message }))
})
```

I've read that most of the time if the error is produced by the middleware it is due to multiple `next()` calls, but that doesn't apply here, unless I'm missing something obvious.

When I remove the `cacheControl` middleware from the application, there is no longer an error, but I can't figure out what in the function is causing the error! Any pointers are helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because `res.json()` is firing twice:

```
app.get('/missions', (req, res) => {
  if (req.useCache) res.status(200).json({ result: cache })

  fetch(dumpUrl)
    .then(data => data.text())
    .then(result => {
      cache = result
      res.status(200).json({ result })
    })
    .catch(e => res.status(500).json({ result: e.message }))
})

// if res.useCase is true, set headers and reply
if (req.useCache) res.status(200).json({ result: cache })

// then fetch and reply again (which generates the error)
fetch(dumpUrl)
    .then(data => data.text())
    .then(result => {
      cache = result
      res.status(200).json({ result })
```

Change it to this to utilize explicit return

```
app.get('/missions', (req, res) => {
  if (req.useCache) return res.status(200).json({ result: cache })

  return fetch(dumpUrl)
    .then(data => data.text())
    .then(result => {
      cache = result
      res.status(200).json({ result })
    })
    .catch(e => res.status(500).json({ result: e.message }))
})
```

The nature of the error is similar to when you do this:

problem

```js
    function problem() {
        if (true === true) console.log('send problem')
        console.log('send garbage by accident')
    }
    console.log(problem())
```

solution

```js
    function solution() {
        if (true === true) return console.log('send solution')
        return console.log('send nothing')
    }
    console.log(solution())
```

`return` is how you exit a function. Your issue is that your code was checking the `if` condition, but then continuing past it because it wasn't told to stop once it found that condition.

The old way or less terse way to write your function would be like:

```
app.get('/missions', (req, res) => {
  if (req.useCache) {
    res.status(200).json({ result: cache })
  } else {
    fetch(dumpUrl)
      .then(data => data.text())
      .then(result => {
        cache = result
        res.status(200).json({ result })
      })
      .catch(e => res.status(500).json({ result: e.message }))
  }
})
```

Without the `else` in there, it executes every if statement it comes across until it reaches the end of the function, unless you use the `return` keyword as the cue to exit right there.

Keep in mind, using `return` inside a `.then()` function will resolve the promise, it won't exit from the upper scope if there are more `.then()`s chained on.